# How to deal with infinite size

Tags: flutter

I was coding my flutter project when I fall under this error. I do not understand because I have tried all the available solution online and still it is not working. The craziest thing is I have the exact same code on the other page and it is working perfectly.
And If I restart the app it works. The first problem was a Material app which is the main function and even if I wrap the column with a scaffold it still doesn't work
Below is the error

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#20590 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=358.0, 0.0<=h<=731.0)
...  layer: OffsetLayer#17148
...    engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#48e1c
...    handles: 2
...    offset: Offset(16.0, 63.0)
...  size: Size(358.0, 731.0)
The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=358.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(358.0, Infinity)
```

Below this I have form that receives data from another one

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loading_overlay/loading_overlay.dart';
import 'package:tembea/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:tembea/components/show_toast.dart';
import 'package:tembea/components/time_pick.dart';
import 'package:tembea/screens/admin/admin_screens/restaurant/dashboard_restaurant.dart';
import '../../../../../constants.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:tembea/components/square_button.dart';
import 'dart:io' ;
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'add_images.dart';

class RestaurantSecondaryForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const RestaurantSecondaryForm({
    Key? key,
    required this.name,
    required this.location,
    required this.price,
    required this.description,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String name;
  final String location;
  final String price;
  final String description;

  @override
  _RestaurantSecondaryFormState createState() => _RestaurantSecondaryFormState();
}

class _RestaurantSecondaryFormState extends State<RestaurantSecondaryForm> {
  bool showSpinner = false;
  String selectedOpeningTime = '8:00 AM';
  String selectedClosingTime = '17:00 PM';
  String ? selectedTime;
  final List<String> defaultImageList = [
    'assets/images/image.png',
    'assets/images/image.png',
    'assets/images/image.png',
  ];
  List<String> imageList =[];
  List<File> files = [];
  List<String> ? imageUrl;
  TaskSnapshot? snap;
  String ? photoUrl;
  String ? photoUrl2;
  String ? photoUrl3;
  String selectedType = 'Restaurant';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<void> openTimePicker(context) async {
      final TimeOfDay? t =
          await showTimePicker(
              context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now());
      if(t != null){
        setState(() {
          selectedTime = t.format(context);
        });
      }
    }
    goToAddImage() async{
      List<String> imgUrl = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context){
        return const AddImages();
      }));
      setState(() {
        imageUrl = imgUrl;
      });
    }
    if(imageUrl?.isNotEmpty == true){
      setState(() {
        photoUrl = imageUrl?[0];
        photoUrl2 = imageUrl?[1];
        photoUrl3 = imageUrl?[2];
        imageList.add(photoUrl!);
        imageList.add(photoUrl2!);
        imageList.add(photoUrl3!);
      });
    }
    else{
      setState(() {
        photoUrl = '';
        photoUrl2 = '';
        photoUrl3 = '';
      });
    }
    return LoadingOverlay(
        isLoading: showSpinner,
        opacity: 0.5,
        color: Colors.green,
        progressIndicator: const CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Add Restaurant'),
            backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor.withOpacity(0.3),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CarouselSlider(
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                      autoPlay: false,
                    ),
                    items:imageList.isEmpty ? defaultImageList.map((e) => ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      child: Stack(
                        fit: StackFit.expand,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            e,
                            width: 1000,
                            height: 300,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )).toList()
                        : imageList.map((e) => ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      child: Stack(
                        fit: StackFit.expand,
                        children: [
                          Image.network(
                            e,
                            width: 1000,
                            height: 300,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )).toList(),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    DateButton(
                      text: 'Upload Images',
                      onPressed: () {
                        goToAddImage();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    TimePick(
                      label: 'Opens at',
                      labelColor: Colors.green,
                      time: selectedOpeningTime,
                      onPressed: (){
                        openTimePicker(context).then((value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedOpeningTime = selectedTime!;
                          });
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    TimePick(
                        label: 'Closes at',
                        labelColor: Colors.red,
                        time: selectedClosingTime,
                        onPressed: (){
                          openTimePicker(context).then((value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedClosingTime = selectedTime!;
                            });
                          });
                        }
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                RoundedButton(
                    buttonName: 'Add Restaurant',
                    color: Colors.green,
                    onPressed: () async{
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = true;
                      });
                      final time = DateTime.now();
                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('activities').doc().set({
                        'Name' : widget.name,
                        'Location': widget.location,
                        'Description' : widget.description,
                        'Price' : widget.price,
                        'OpeningTime' : selectedOpeningTime,
                        'ClosingTime' : selectedClosingTime,
                        'PhotoUrl' : photoUrl,
                        'PhotoUrl2' : photoUrl2,
                        'PhotoUrl3' : photoUrl3,
                        'Type' : selectedType,
                        'ts' : time,
                      }).then((value) {
                        setState(() {
                          showSpinner = false;
                        });
                        showToast(message: 'Restaurant Added',
                            color: Colors.green
                        );
                        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, DashboardRestaurant.id, (r) => false);
                      });
                    }
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

which is supposed to navigate back to this view that brings the error

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tembea/components/add_button.dart';
import 'package:tembea/components/responsive.dart';
import 'package:tembea/components/show_dialog.dart';
import 'package:tembea/components/show_toast.dart';
import 'package:tembea/screens/admin/admin_screens/view_data.dart';
import 'event_form.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


class DashboardEvent extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardEvent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String id = 'dashboard_event';

  @override
  _DashboardEventState createState() => _DashboardEventState();
}

class _DashboardEventState extends State<DashboardEvent> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> activities = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance.collection('activities')
      .where('Type', isEqualTo: 'Event')
      .orderBy('ts', descending: true)
      .snapshots();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children:  [
         AddButton(
           title: 'Events',
           addLabel: 'Add Events',
           onPressed: (){
             Navigator.pushNamed(context, EventForm.id);
           },),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 16.0,
        ),
        const Divider(
          color: Colors.white70,
          height:40.0,
        ),
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: activities,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),
                  ),
                );
              }
              final data = snapshot.requireData;
              if(data != null){
                return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: data.size,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  radius: 40,
                                  child:Image.network(
                                    data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl'],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text( data.docs[index]['Name'], style:const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

                                ),
                                if(Responsive.isWeb(context))
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 50,
                                  ),
                                Responsive.isWeb(context) ? ButtonBlue(
                                  addLabel: 'View Event',
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                                      return ViewData(item: data.docs[index],);
                                    }));
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(IconData(61161, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
                                ) : InkWell(
                                  onTap: (){
                                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                                      return ViewData(item: data.docs[index],);
                                    }));
                                  },
                                  child: const Icon(IconData(61161, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
                                ),
                                Responsive.isWeb(context) ? ButtonBlue(
                                  addLabel: 'Delete Event',
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    showDialog(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context){
                                          return ShowDialog(
                                            deleteFunction: () async{
                                              await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                                                FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl']).delete();
                                                myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
                                              }).then((value) => Navigator.pop(context));
                                            },
                                            dialogTitle: "Delete",
                                            dialogContent: "Do you really want to delete ${data.docs[index]['Name']} event?",
                                          );
                                        });
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_outline,),
                                ): InkWell(
                                  onTap: (){
                                    if(defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS){
                                      showCupertinoDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (BuildContext context){
                                            return ShowDialog(
                                              deleteFunction: () async{
                                                await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                                                  FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl']).delete();
                                                  myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
                                                }).then((value) => Navigator.pop(context));
                                              },
                                              dialogTitle: "Delete",
                                              dialogContent: "Do you really want to delete ${data.docs[index]['Name']} event?",
                                            );
                                          });
                                    }
                                      else if((defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android)){
                                      showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (BuildContext context){
                                            return ShowDialog(
                                              deleteFunction: () async{
                                                await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                                                  FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl']).delete();
                                                  myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
                                                }).then((value) => Navigator.pop(context));
                                              },
                                              dialogTitle: "Delete",
                                              dialogContent: "Do you really want to delete ${data.docs[index]['Name']} event?",
                                            );
                                          });
                                    }
                                      else{
                                      showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (BuildContext context){
                                            return ShowDialog(
                                              deleteFunction: () async{
                                                await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                                                  FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl']).delete();
                                                  myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
                                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                                  showToast(message: 'Deleted Successfully', color: Colors.green);
                                                }).then((value) => Navigator.pop(context));
                                              },
                                              dialogTitle: "Delete",
                                              dialogContent: "Do you really want to delete ${data.docs[index]['Name']} event?",
                                            );
                                          });
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child:  const Icon(Icons.delete_outline,),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            const Divider(
                              color: Colors.white70,
                              height:40.0,
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                    });
              }
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have been on this the entire day but in vain but in the same product, I have another view details with the same code that works
Please assist me on this

Comment: Even though I don't fully understand you problem, I see few mistakes : Don't declare : openTimePicker and goToAddImage in your build methode. And also setState. The build methode is triggered multiple time. It can cause multiple problem

Comment: If you can say which line or widget cause infinite size.

Comment: The problem is I don't know I wrapped everything with expanded on that page and the error persisted

Comment: But I know it is in the last code snippet

Comment: Try to wrap the Text widget with FittedBox( fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,....) Because If you don't know the length of the Name it can cause problem. Else if you don't say which widget...